# Unity Build (Win10) Crashes - Access Violation (0xc0000005)

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash

I got a problem with my Unity App build for Windows10, it is crashing randomly.

My system: Intel NUC8, Windows 10, Unity 2019.2.1f
I'm using an external touchscreen monitor, not sure if this is important.

What I have already tried:

- run app as administrator
- disabled wifi, firewall, anti virus
- the windows 10 on the pc is pretty clean, nothing other installed

Not sure what else I can try... :(

See error log file below:

### Error Log:

```
JLR Touchscreen App by ME [version: Unity 2019.2.1f1_ca4d5af0be6f]

d3d11.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module d3d11.dll at 0033:7c3df4f0.

Error occurred at 2019-11-12_011246.
C:\Users\this2\Documents\Touchscreen App.exe, run by this2.

29% physical memory in use.
8061 MB physical memory [5719 MB free].
387 MB process peak paging file [281 MB used].
367 MB process peak working set [264 MB used].
System Commit Total/Limit/Peak: 2280MB/9341MB/2562MB
System Physical Total/Available: 8061MB/5719MB
System Process Count: 145
System Thread Count: 1519
System Handle Count: 51188
Disk space data for 'C:\Users\this2\AppData\Local\Temp\ME\Touchscreen App\Crashes\Crash_2019-11-12_091243819\': 220660408320 bytes free of 255383826432 total.

Read from location 000000000000012C caused an access violation.

Context:
RDI:    0x0000000000000000  RSI: 0x0000015309b8e9c0  RAX:   0x0000000000000100
RBX:    0x0000000000000036  RCX: 0x0000015309b8e9c0  RDX:   0x0000000000000000
RIP:    0x00007ff87c3df4f0  RBP: 0x00000031f4bfe841  SegCs: 0x0000000000000033
EFlags: 0x0000000000010206  RSP: 0x00000031f4bfe780  SegSs: 0x000000000000002b
R8:     0x0000000000000000  R9:  0x00000031f4bfe8d8  R10:   0x00000153083b8d40
R11:    0x00007ff83fbe1ff8  R12: 0x0000000000000000  R13:   0x0000015309b8e8e0
R14:    0x0000000000000100  R15: 0x0000000000000100


Bytes at CS:EIP:
44 0f b6 9a 2c 01 00 00 4c 8b f1 8b 8a d8 00 00 

Mono DLL loaded successfully at 'C:\Users\this2\Documents\JLR\MonoBleedingEdge\EmbedRuntime\mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll'.

Stack Trace of Crashed Thread 5820:
0x00007FF87C3DF4F0 (d3d11) CreateDirect3D11SurfaceFromDXGISurface
0x00007FF83ED30B8B (UnityPlayer) PAL_Thread_SupportsThreads
0x00007FF83ED2907F (UnityPlayer) PAL_Thread_SupportsThreads
0x00007FF83EDB29A3 (UnityPlayer) PAL_Thread_SupportsThreads
0x00007FF83EDB864B (UnityPlayer) PAL_Thread_SupportsThreads
0x00007FF83EDB8728 (UnityPlayer) PAL_Thread_SupportsThreads
0x00007FF83F0B9D08 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FF884F07BD4 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FF88560CED1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Comment: Interesting update, I replaced the touchscreen with a normal monitor and the app isn't crashing anymore...Anyone an idea how this is related?